# Batch with docx

Tags: python-docx

I am trying to write few lines to look for a string in the paragraphs on several docx files in a single folder. I have managed to open the docx in the folder one by one but not yet to find and print the paragraph containing a specific string, any hint is highly appreciated.

```
import docx
import glob
from docx import Document
for document in glob.iglob("*.docx"):
 document=Document()
 for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
  if 'String' in paragraph.text:
   print paragraph.text
  else:
   print ('not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing a filename with a `python-pptx` `Document` object.

What you need is something like this:

```
import glob
from docx import Document

for filename in glob.iglob('*.docx'):
    document = Document(filename)
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if 'String' in paragraph.text:
            print paragraph.text
        else:
            print 'not found'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the point is that if I introduce the name of a file, it would process specifically that single file and not the others in the folder.